# Get first and second result from (values) lisp

Tags: lisp

Say i send this code to the clisp interpreter:

> (values 'a 'b) 
>   A ; 
>   B

Now i wish to record this information (using a setf) and to access both A and B from the results.
How can i, later, access both the values there?
I tried doing:

> (setf result (values 'a 'b)) 
>   A

It only stores 'A and not 'B. How can i do this?

Comment: You should look into [multiple-value-bind](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_multip.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, functions in lisp can return multiple values via the values form. If you want to bind the values to variables, you can use multiple-value-bind. Example

```
(multiple-value-bind (a b c) (values 1 2 3) (+ a b c))
```

1 will be bound to a, 2 will be bound to b, 3 will be bound to c, and so the result of evaluating the form will be 6. If you tried to setf a values form to a var, then only the first value will be used.

Comment: By the way, if you want just store result in some place, `setf` is enaugh: `(setf (values x y) (values 1 2))`.